# how could i put single quote (') instead of double(") to make a mongodb aggregate in vert.x?

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I am trying to execute this mongo aggregate with vertx runCommand :

```
"$group" : {
  "_id" : '$code_barque',
  "date_e" : {
    "$first" : '$date_e'
  },
  "nom_nav" : {
    "$first" : '$nom_nav'
  },
  "code_b" : {
    "$first" : '$code_b'
  },
  "position" : {
    "$first" : '$position'
  },
  "date_pos" : {
    "$first" : '$date_pos'
  }
}
```

The problem is , how to put ('$date_e' , '$nom_nav' , ...) with simple quotes in my JsonObject query ?

Thanks for your given time.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use single quotes? Why would you think the type of quotes should be different for key and values? The only thing JSON cares about is that keys are quoted ( single or double does not matter ) and that values are valid as numeric, boolean or string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've found an issue , thank you ; the probleme was in my query .